# All sections, title, image, icon etc. has merged into single text editor in Elementor. What to do?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

As you can see in the image, the layout of the page has messed up. When I try to edit the page with elementor, it shows only a text editor inside a container. The page originally contained many sections, columns, icon etc widgets.
[screenshot when trying to edit the page with elementor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y2Bc.png)
[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM08s.png)

Comment: Same issue was raised in stack exchange but was dropped without solution considering it a 3rd party topic. Link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/408628/elementor-combined-all-sections-into-1-text-editor